# Would moving data from one table to a 2nd table improve update speed?

Tags: mysql

I have a large MyISAM table of about 300K records. Most of it is short strings and ints, however, one field contains compressed data of about 5-10K for each record. The data field is rarely updated but the other fields are updated several times per hour.

Would it speed up table selects/updates if I moved the data field into another table referenced by the primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is normally not useful to split a table into different tables just because the rows become large. In accessing a row, the biggest performance hit is the disk seek needed to find the first byte of the row. After finding the data, most modern disks can read the entire row fast enough for most applications. The only cases where splitting up a table makes an appreciable difference is if it is a MyISAM table using dynamic row format that you can change to a fixed row size, or if you very often need to scan the table but do not need most of the columns. See Chapter 14, Storage Engines.

I think your case fits the last case, so **yes** it would speed up selects. (Maybe not updates)

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-queries-myisam.html